# 2017 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, moderator-election

The 2017 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at:

https://stackoverflow.com/election

for more details, and also to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: What, if anything, is this question for?  Is there anything we're supposed to do here?

Comment: @Jeffrey Bosboom: The community user posts this to announce the start of an election, and has done this for every election in the last six years. I don't think it needs to do this anymore, since the election now appears prominently in the community bulletin.

Comment: @BoltCLock that, plus the community wiki status of the post made it look like Krunal had posted it (which isn't what happened).

Comment: @Pekka 웃: Yeah, that's true. I came here from noticing that they had tagged both this and [their question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/353687/why-does-the-moderator-election-require-nominees-to-have-3000-reputation-points) [election-2017] (probably unaware that we don't do by-year election tags)

Comment: @BoltClock Also weird that despite you rolling back the edit, Krunal is still listed as the last editor on the question. Is that deliberate?

Comment: @BhargavRao um...why did you reopen the **2017** version of this question?  Did you think that the 2018 version had been deleted?

Comment: Uh no @Servy, I voted to reopen because it was an announcement which was closed and deleted wrongly.

Comment: @BhargavRao But it's a year old, and has no useful information (it hasn't had any relevant information to convey since the election ended).  It's completely obsolete.  Even if it didn't merit closure *then*, it merits closure *now*.

Comment: @Servy Interesting, why does this one particular election announcement merit closure, whereas the other 6 obsolete ones don't? Anyway feel free to vote to close it again, and let us leave it to the review queue to decide

Comment: Let's vtc as _so last year_.

Comment: @BhargavRao Where did I say that the other 6 aren't obsolete?  You've fallen into the common trap of saying that because one close-worthy question is open all other close-worthy questions should remain open.

Comment: Okay @Servy, I locked it as historically significant. It doesn't merit closure. If you want to discuss further about it, please open a new [tag:discussion] on Meta