# Why does the moderator election require nominees to have 3,000 reputation points

Tags: discussion, moderation, moderator-election

Moderator election nomination has begun but there is a minimum of [3,000](https://stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) points. Why can't a candidate below 3000 points be eligible for moderation? The Stack Overflow privilege table/list states:

- [2,000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) - They trust candidate on Stack Overflow website and allows candidate to edit anything (question/answer) on this site.
- [10,000](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools) - They allow an access to moderation tools.

Questions:

1. Why can't a candidate with 2,000 points be nominated for election, while they trust candidate at that stage?
2. How can an elected moderator (with points less than 10,000) moderate this website, without having an access to moderation tools?

Comment: As to your second question, a diamond mod gets access moderator tools and have to sign an agreement with SO with respect to user data they are privy to

Comment: For your first question, they likely only want nominees who have cast close and reopen votes. You don't get the privilege of helping close and reopen questions until you reach 3000 rep.

Comment: Realistically and honestly, it is *very* unlikely for someone with 3,000 rep to get elected as a moderator. Not impossible, but unlikely.

Comment: I'm almost at 10.500 rep and still learning new things about this community. I believe that being a moderator is not as simple and straightforward  as it seem. Editing posts is one thing, being in charge of thousands of users is another

Comment: @AlonEitan I agree with you and that's why I've this question. Is 3000 sufficient? Or criteria should be something elese

Comment: @Krunal It depends. I've seen users with much less reputation than mine that I still consider as a better SO users then myself. Reputations is a bid deal, but there are other important criterias  to consider

Comment: If someone has less than 3K reputation, they haven't handled close votes before. You're expected to have a minimum amount of moderation experience (personally, I think gold badges for working the review queues are *very* important when voting for new moderators) and you can't really easily get that with less than 3K.

Answer (score 8):

> 1. Why can't a candidate with 2000 points be nominated for election, while they trust candidate on that stage?

The 3k rep threshold is unique to SO; other sites have a minimum of 300. In the case of SO, it's simple practicality: since most elections easily fill the slate of all 30 nominees that the software will handle, and since only the top 30 nominees by rep will be retained for the primary, there's a rep threshold to have an effective nomination that, in most cases, will hit 3k by itself before the election hits the second stage. So it's more efficient to *start* with a reasonable basic threshold to avoid having to wade through dozens or hundreds of low-rep nominees that don't really have any chance of even getting to the primary, never mind the final election, never mind actually *being* elected. And it helps reduce bitter disappointment among those who naively suppose that just because the software lets them nominate themselves, they actually have *any* chance of being elected with, say, 2088 rep: no SO mod has ever, to my knowledge, been elected with less than 10k, even way back in early days.

> 2. How an elected moderator (with points less than 10000) moderate this website, without having an access to moderation tools?

♦ mods, whatever their reputation, have full access to all ♦ mod tools, including unlimited binding (one-vote) close/reopen, delete/undelete, spam-flagging, protection/unprotection, and of course editing privileges, as well as various miscellaneous tools to investigate users, modify site settings, and so forth. Election (or being an SE employee) is worth more in its own right than any amount of rep.

Comment: For context, this is how many candidates SO elections had: 55, 28, 18, 27, 30, 32, 19, 12, 12 (currently). That's with 3K requirement;  one could expect many more with 300.

Comment: I thought Adam Lear was elected with less than 10K rep?